# Cannot add hostPath to under volumes in custom SCC

Tags: openshift

I have an OpenShift custom SCC which I have deployed.
I want to add `hostPath` to the volumes section. 
I use the following command:

```
$ oc edit scc custom-scc
```

Add line

```
- hostPath
```

Save and exit

Upon returning to edit I see that nothing my addition was removed.

I don't have this problem with other edits such as capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to also add:

```
allowHostDirVolumePlugin: true
```